# Extending Classes in Java

Tags: java, android

I am trying to extend a class to multiple other classes e.g.

```
public class Ability extends Character
```

Due to this i am getting an error in my code:

> Implicit super constructor Character() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor    Defense.java

My code is:

```
public class Character {
    int characterID;
    double characterHealth;

    public Character(int charID, double charHealth) {
        characterID = charID;
        characterHealth = charHealth;
    }
}

public class Defense extends Character {
    int armorClass;
    int difficultyClass;

    public Defense(int newAC, int newDC){
        armorClass = newAC;
        difficultyClass = newDC;
    }
}
```

I am unsure of how to invoke another constructor. 
If someone could point out why and how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a sub-class ctor:

```
super(charId, charHealth);
```

Since the superclass has no default constructor you must explicitly call a non-default constructor.

Comment: Hmm see I was going to try doing that using the autogenerated program part that the program can do. Ill give it a go thanks.

What is the comparison with the extends key word to the : in c#? Because if I recall the : requires no super method to be used, or is the : not the same as extends?

Comment: @VasaSerafin Construction semantics are different, in that as soon as you define a ctor with no args there is no *implicit* default (no-arg) generated for you automatically. As soon as there's no default ctor in a superclass you must explicitly call one--that's just the way Java is.

Comment: So essentially what you are saying is that the super is created in C# also just in the back-end of the program? Is there a less messy way to define the super though, because at the moment the coding for that could get very long due to all the variables that are used.

Also just for clarification if I was to serialize the Character object, would the serialization encompass the other classes?

Comment: @Vasaserafin I don't know how C# does it. But if you create an instance of a subclass you'd still need to initialize those variables somehow. Constructors aren't necessarily the best way to do verbose initialization; depending on needs a builder might be better, etc. Serializing serializes an instance--it's not that there's an instance of the subclass *and* an instance of the superclass, there is only an instance of the subclass--which included all the properties if the superclass. A simple test would demonstrate that.

Comment: OK thanks again makes sense, I am predominantly a C# programmer and have taken a paper that teaches Android, although I have not done Java for a year or more.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you would get the values for `charId` and `charHealth`, perhaps those are constants, but here is how you do it:

```
public Defense(int newAC, int newDC)
{
    super(charId, charHealth);
    armorClass = newAC;
    difficultyClass = newDC;
}
```

Comment: *"I'm not sure where you would get the values ..."* - Probably by adding parameters to the subclass constructor.  But yea, he's got a design issue there ...

Comment: Hmm see I was going to try doing that using the autogenerated program part that the program can do. Ill give it a go thanks.